# c# console program divides 6 by 2 and gets 27

Tags: c#, console-application, division

something went wrong in c# while coding a project, it divides and multiplies all different datatypes and results 27 or 26 or 108 , how to resolve ?!
[image]

Comment: post your code istead of image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, code using `Console.Read` to read an integer, but `Console.Read` reads next character from input stream (Will not wait for `enter`). Moment when  type `67`, first character(`6`) will be converted to `int` and assigned to variable `a` immediately, so `a` gets `54` (ASCII value).

Which will get divided by `2` results `27`

To fix your problem, use [`Console.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx), which reads the line of characters.

```
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // or use `int.TryParse`
```

Answer (score 5):

`Console.Read()` reads a character from the keyboard, and lets you store it where you want. You typed a `6`, which may look like a number to you, but to the computer is merely another character, like `A`, `!` or `&`.

The character '6' has the (ASCII) code 54. Divide that by 2 and you get 27...